# How to access information from a class used in one method a different method?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm writing a text-based adventure game in which I would like to access information from a class that is used in one method for another. What I intend to do is have the character information in a thread and then have this printed to a text document at any time during the game in a similar way to a pause menu.

I will attempt to write an example of what I would like to do below.

```
class Player
{
    public int health;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        player.health = 20;
    }

    public static void method2()
    {
        //Here I want to access the "player" in the Main method.

        //Then I want to print this and other stats to a text document:
        string[] lines = { "Stat 1", "Stat 2", "Stat 3" };

         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking everything out of main, and then making a game class that contains a player. This way you have access to the player when you need it, and you don't have to pass it back and forth. You can also initialize the player health when you instantiate it.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Game myGame = new Game();
        myGame.PlayGame();
    }
}
public class Game
{
    public Player myPlayer = new Player();

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        // place your loop / logic here to request input from the user and update your game state
    }

    public void WritePLayerStats()
    {
        string[] lines = { myPlayer.stat1, myPlayer.stat2 };

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);

        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
    }

}

public class Player
{
    public int health = 20;

    public string stat1 = "";

    public string stat2 = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in `Player` to your `method2()`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Player player = new Player();
    player.health = 20;
    method2(player);
}

public static void method2(Player player)
{
    //Here I want to access the "player" in the Main method.

    //Then I want to print this and other stats to a text document:
    string[] lines = { player.health, "Stat 1", "Stat 2", "Stat 3" };

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);

    Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
}
```

You can also move your method into the `Player` object, for example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        player.health = 20;
        player.PrintStatistics();
    }
}   

public class Player
{
    public int health;

    public void PrintStatistics()
    {
        //Here I want to access the "player" in the Main method.

        //Then I want to print this and other stats to a text document:
        string[] lines = { this.health, "Stat 1", "Stat 2", "Stat 3" };

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);

        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways, you can pass the value into the method by calling it with the player instance as a parameter.

```
public static void method2(Player player)
{
    string[] lines = { "Stat 1", "Stat 2", "Stat 3" };

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
    Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Player player = new Player();
     player.health = 20;
     method2(player);
}
```

Or you can make it a static member of the class and use Main to setup the class before starting your game's logic

```
public class Program
{
    private static Player player;

    public static void method2()
    {
        string[] lines = { "Stat 1", "Stat 2", "Stat 3" };

         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
         Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         player = new Player();
         player.health = 20;

         method2(player);
    }
}
```